# Troubles running .py file using crontab

Tags: python, terminal, cron

Ive written a script to generate a time sheet based off a word template. This ideally will happen weekly and with very little maintenance as is the way with all these things.
Here is my code...

```
import random
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate
from datetime import datetime

dateNow = datetime.today().strftime("%d.%m.%y")

jobs = ["job1", "job2", "job3"]

doc = DocxTemplate("Template.docx")
mon = random.choice(jobs)
tue = random.choice(jobs)
wed = random.choice(jobs)
thur = random.choice(jobs)
fri = random.choice(jobs)

context = {'mon' : mon, 'tue' : tue, 'wed' : wed, 'thur' : thur, 'fri' : fri, 'date' : dateNow}

doc.render(context)

doc.save(r'/Users/pathToSaveLocation/' + "{}".format(dateNow) + ".docx")
```

this runs and does exactly what i want it to which is great!
this is my crontab...

```
***** python absolutePathToScript/main.py
```

When i run this from ~/ it works and generates the file i need. From crontab i get nadah.

**Some things to note:**
-im aware how cron tab works in regards to '*'. Im only using 5 *'s for testing purposes.
-Im on a mac
-Im a fairly new python programmer

Thanks for your help in advance

Tried these:
-Using absolute paths vs paths from my home folder.
-Changed the folder my script was located in to see if that was the issue
-I double checked that my terminal had the rights to perform actions apropriately
-I checked my crontab was actually able to do things by making it play a sound every minute which actually worked.

none of these gave me any results on the actual thing i wanted to happen.

Comment: By default, any output from a `cron` job gets mailed to its owner. Unfortunately, since almost no computer these days has mail set up properly, that message ends up in a place where nobody reads it. However, you can still read it by running the `mail` command in a terminal. That might give some clues to what is going on.

Comment: Check to see if you are running the cron jobs as the superuser or regular user. Superuser and regular user have different crontab.

Comment: @TurePålsson i get this in the message about the process xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun

Comment: @MichaelSohnen Im on a mac as the main user. Im pretty sure im the super user by deafult on a mac right?

Comment: Hm, which Python installation are you trying to use? I *suspect* that this is a PATH issue, and that the cron job, for some reason, is picking up the Python that comes with Xcode, but when running manually, you’re using some other Python. Try using the full path to the Python binary, instead of just `python`.

Comment: @TurePålsson so ive just updated my cron to specifically run it from my install of python3.11. i get this. /bin/sh: python3.11: command not found.  so now im thinking you may be right. something isnt connecting somewhere

Comment: Still cant get this to work. Ive checked paths,  wiped and reinstalled pyton3.11, went DEEP checking permissions on my machines settings and even set it up using sudo. nothing,... The error code changed slightly. ```/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file '/Users/jamesreed/Desktop/TimeSheetAutomation/main.py': [Errno 1] Operation not permitted```. Im getting desperate.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was calling the wrong version of Python. The correct call looks like this

```
0 9 * * 0 /usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/user/Desktop/TimeSheetAutomation/main.py 2>&1
```

This fixed the issue instantly.